# Android resource linking failed (Gradle build error)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-resources

The issue described below seems to have arisen simply because I erroneously wrote

> android:id="@android:id/android:list"

in a layout. The reference to android:list caused no problems through many updates of the app both in Eclipse and Android Studio, but after the latest Gradle update it caused the Gradle build to fall over. Simply amending the code to

> android:id="@android:id/list"

solved the problem.

---

After accepting a Gradle update the Gradle build has failed reporting

> "Android resource linking failed"

and the error

```
C:\Users\...\AndroidStudioProjects\com. ...\app\src\main\res\layout\textsummarylist.xml:7: AAPT: error: resource android:id/android:list not found.
```

The Project build.gradle file reads

```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

The Module build.gradle file reads

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.prepbgg.mymap"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/jcoord-1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jcoord-1.0.jar')
}
```

The textsummarylist.xml file reads:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I solve this, please?

---

Background:
I'm modifying an app which I've been using satisfactorily on several devices, and occasionally improving, for several years. It is for my personal use and I need it to run on an old phone running Android version 4.1.2 and my current phone with Android version 10.

All was well until yesterday when I followed a prompt to update Gradle.

When I encounter Gradle errors I look to Stackoverflow for advice on how to correct them.

After the update the Gradle build first reported the warning

> Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.

I've not yet tried to make any changes. I don't know what, if anything, needs to be changed.

The next message was

> The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (29.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.1.

So, I've edited the reference to the SDK Build Tools version in the Module build.gradle files (see below).

The next issue was

> Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.0.1-6197926. Searched in the following locations: - ...

Following advice on StackOverflow I've inserted a reference to google() in the Project build.gradle file.

The "Resource linking failed" error came at the next build attempt.

Answer (score 0):

After editing android:id="@android:id/android:list" to read android:id="@android:id/list" the app has been built and installed successfully.

It seems that the reference to "@android:id/list" has passed all previous checks in Eclipse and Android Studio, but now Gradle has objected!